# How to treat hopelessly stupid questions

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

I'm baffled here. I have searched Meta, but didn't find this problem. (There are many different types of "stupid question" discussions, though - but not about this kind.)

The question itself is not stupid, but looking at the posted code, there is hardly 10% of code that is right there. It actually looks like someone was looking at a low quality printout of code and retyped it with very limited programming knowledge. Or - in some cases - like some dadaist poem, the words actually make sense, but the whole code just looks like a random collection of programming terms.

For example:

```
For i = 1 To Len(n) Step -1
    i = Mid(n, i, 1)
```

`n` was an input string from an input box, `i` was declared as integer. WTF...

Now, my problem is, the actual question the asker asks is valid, I can answer it (though in these cases it is usually a syntax error). But... seriously... I don't see how solving one minor issue in a code that is complete gibberish would help anyone.

So, my question is: **Should I close vote questions like these? With what reason?** It is not off-topic, it is well worded, clear what is being asked, there is effort shown, and sometimes the actual question is not about a simple typographical error...

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708924/converting-binary-to-decimal-using-loop#34708924)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579256/create-an-option-for-copy-code): Here basically all the constants are mistyped ("x1None" instead of "xlNone") - I have seen things like this in beginner VBA classes when people tried to hand copy a code from the projector screen...

Comment: I'd go with "Unclear what you are asking for". Whilst the *requirement* might be clear the **real** reasons behind it are not. Whether you answer as well is entirely up to you.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks. But the questions are pretty clear for example in my 2nd example, so a quick look from a moderator will decline my flag. As for the duplicate, not really, the questions are not basic. The askers might be novices, but the actual question is sometimes OK. It is the rest of the code...

Comment: No moderator would be involved. Close votes just accumulate or age out.

Comment: If there isn't already a duplicate question, and the question is reasonably scoped and clear, answer it!

Answer (score 10):

> It is not off-topic, it is well worded, clear what is being asked, there is effort shown, and sometimes the actual question is not about a simple typographical error...

From that, it sounds like these questions should either:

- be **upvoted**, if they're concise enough to get an answer,
- be **answered** if you understand what it is they're trying to get at, or
- **edited into shape** to make them more accessible for others.

The fact that the code contained in the question was bad is...well, I'd say that's almost expected nowadays.  (Not saying anything about VB here.)  The nature of Stack Overflow has mostly pigeonholed would-be askers into presenting what code they've tried to work with and have clearly failed in doing so, leaving them open to our direct ridicule.

What we're really caring about here is the *question*.  Is the *question* good?  If it is, then there's no reason not to answer it.

Comment: Thanks, actually you are right. Still hurts though, especially knowing that after I answer, they will come back to ask 100 more questions about their useless codes...

Comment: @vacip:  C'mon, it isn't like you started programming with immaculate and flawless code... Cut them some slack.  At least they're trying to learn.  Also, Stack Overflow does a pretty good job of limiting an individual's flood of poor questions.

Comment: @Makoto: there is a Close reason in the standard list for stupid typos. A question about a program that does not work because someone learns through Cargo Cult Programming is not likely to help anyone else.

Comment: @Jongware:  I'm well aware of that close reason, but the OP pointed out that there are times when they *aren't* typos.  Closing a question because it's a typo when it actually isn't is counterproductive at best.

Comment: Well, would the question's answer help anyone else? If not, as Boltclock said, it's still the right reason, because the meat of the reason is "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers".

Comment: @Deduplicator:  I'd leave that more for the people who understand that technology to answer, really.  It wouldn't be fair for me to make that assertion if I don't understand the platform.  However, in my mind, and from what has been described, if the question can be answered in a way that can help others, there's nothing to gain from closing it outright.  I maintain that the OP is asking about questions which *aren't* typos or temporal.  At least, that's the intention that my answer has.

Comment: How this got downvoted is beyond me. Now people are against answering on-topic reasonably scoped clear questions? What is next?

Comment: If the question is about a typo, I usually flag the question, but also point out the solution in a comment and ask the OP to delete his question. However when the question itself is not about one of the many typos in the displayed code, I do answer, but id is a bit frustrating. I think this frustration explains the downvotes: it is really annoying when you answer a question while knowing that OP doesn't have a clue what he is doing.

Comment: @vacip Everyone at some point had no clue what they were doing.

Comment: @Magisch That is true. Still, if someone comes to me asking for earplugs because he can't sleep from a loud cracking noise, and his whole house is violently on fire, quietly handing him the earplugs would feel... wrong.

Comment: @vacip so, link to some additional tutorials in a comment.